# Does this sequence of real number converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Given the sequence of real numbers $$a_n = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}\right)- \ln(n+\sqrt{1+n^2}) , n\in \Bbb{N}$$
Test its convergence.

What I did was to separate the sequence from the series and testing the convergence for each of them. Checking the $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n+\sqrt{1+n^2})=\infty$ so the sequence diverges and then by the integral test I found out that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}$ diverges too. Now I don’t know how to go on and states if the sequence diverges or not. Have I used the wrong method?

Comment: When you have split up the sequence, you can't be sure that it diverges just because one part does. A silly example: $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n-n)$ converges, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} n$ diverges.

Comment: @FatouSall: Convergence of $a_n$ means that the sum behaves asymptotically like the log-expression on the r.h.s. This is probably what the problem is about.

Comment: I added brackets around sum (at first I thought that $- \ln$ is a factor in the sum), please check if I did it correctly.

Comment: Are you allowed, in your work, to use the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1} \approx \gamma + \ln n$?

Answer (score 1):

I will prove that

1. $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence;
2. $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded below.

By the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), 1 and 2 imply that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent.

Before proceeding, I note that $\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})=\sinh^{-1}(x)$, so $a_n$ can be rewritten as$^{(*)}$
$$
a_n = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}\right)- \sinh^{-1}(n). \tag{1}
$$

Proof of 1: Since $f(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ is a decreasing function of $x$, one has
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(n+1)^2}}<\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\sinh^{-1}(n+1)-\sinh^{-1}(n), \tag{2}
$$
hence
$$
a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(n+1)^2}}-\sinh^{-1}(n+1)+\sinh^{-1}(n)<0.\quad{\square} \tag{3}
$$
Proof of 2: In a similar vein, one has
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}>\int_1^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
=\sinh^{-1}(n+1)-\sinh^{-1}(1), \tag{4}
$$
hence
$$
a_n > \sinh^{-1}(n+1)-\sinh^{-1}(1)-\sinh^{-1}(n)>-\sinh^{-1}(1). \quad{\square} \tag{5}
$$

---

$^{(*)}$ See, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_functions_as_logarithms.